# Which kanji is this?

Tags: kanji, handwriting

I'd like to know the meaning of the kanji circled in the image (or, simply, what kanji it is). I was able to discern everything else, but because it's handwritten, it was difficult tell what it was.[image]

Comment: 「[数表]{すうひょう}」ですね。(numeric table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like 数 (かず), meaning number.

[image]